# How to speed up deployment to Jetty?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, vaadin, maven-jetty-plugin

Deployment to the Jetty server is very slow (around 45 seconds), which is tough for development, so I'm looking for advice on how to speed it up.

I'm using Maven with the Jetty plugin (jetty-maven-plugin), and the jetty:run goal on a vaadin project created from the archetype com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application.

I found reference here: [wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deploymen), and it makes sense that this is the problem, because there are many jar files to be scanned (from vaadin framework), but I cannot figure out where to put the xml file, what to name it, and how to get the maven jetty:run goal to use it (and I have tried lots of variations that I could think of!)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gregw pointed me in the right direction.  Here is the complete detail of how I ended up resolving this:

1) I added a file named jetty-web.xml in my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder.  It contained:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>nothing.jar</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Note at this point I don't have any jars the need scanning, so I just put in a dummy entry of "nothing.jar" as the pattern to match.

2) Edit the jetty-maven-plugin's entry in pom.xml: in the  section, I added

```html
<contextXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml</contextXml>
```

Now redeploys happen in just a couple seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an individual context in the plugin either by adding attributes/parameters in the web.xml (for some limited things) or using a context xml file that applies to the context, which you need to specify with the contextXml element of the plugin configuration.

See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp

P.S. Jetty 9 is a little faster in scanning etc.